# Explode a string with random length equally to next empty columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I've df like this..

```
                                              string  some_col
0  But were so TESSA tell me a little bit more t ...        10
1                                                           15
2                                                           14
3  Some other text xxxxxxxxxx                               20
```

How can I split `string` col such that long string exploded into random lengths equally across empty cells. It should look like this after fitting.

```
                      string  some_col
0   But were so TESSA tell me .        10
1  little bit more t seems like        15
2              you pretty upset        14
```

Reproducable

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['But were so TESSA tell me a  you pretty upset.', 10], ['', 15], ['', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['string', 'some_col']) 
print(df)
```

I've no idea how to get even started I'm looking for execution steps so that I can implemnt on my own any refrence would be great!

Comment: So, the value in `some_col` doesn't matter? @Bhargav

Comment: Yeah deson't matter.. i just want to fill string col to empty cells

Comment: One way I can think of is: forward fill the strings column, then add a group id to each row (so a number of occurrences of that string so far), then add max occurrences in a new column, then determine the slice based on those two columns (so if you have group ID 2 (second row) and max occurrences 3, you need to dissect the second slice of three slices.

Comment: Do you want to split the sentence by the length of the string or by the number of words?

Comment: Deosn't matter @Corralien ... I just want to explode the string & fill rest of empty columns  such that there should be no empty cells..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
data = [['But were so TESSA tell me a you pretty upset.', 10], ['', 15], ['', 14], 
['Some other long string that you need..', 10], ['', 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['string', 'some_col']) 

df['string'] = np.where(df['string'] == '', None, df['string'])
df.ffill(inplace=True)

df['group_id'] = df.groupby('string').cumcount() + 1
df['max_group_id'] = df.groupby('string',).transform('count')['group_id']

df['string'] = df['string'].str.split(' ')
df['string'] = df.apply(func=lambda r: r['string'][int(ceil(len(r['string'])/r['max_group_id'])*(r['group_id']-1)):
                            int(ceil(len(r['string'])/r['max_group_id'])*r['group_id'])], axis=1)
df.drop(columns=['group_id', 'max_group_id'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                        string  some_col
0       [But, were, so, TESSA]        10
1           [tell, me, a, you]        15
2             [pretty, upset.]        14
3  [Some, other, long, string]        10
4          [that, you, need..]        15
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create groups with a non empty row and all consecutive empty rows (the group length gives the number of chunks) then use `np.split_array` to create n list of words:

```
import numpy as np

#                                             first row --v  group length --v
wrap = lambda x: [' '.join(l) for l in np.array_split(x.iloc[0].split(), len(x))]

df['string2'] = (df.groupby(df['string'].str.len().ne(0).cumsum())['string']
                   .apply(wrap).explode().to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
                                           string  some_col                     string2
0  But were so TESSA tell me a  you pretty upset.        10           But were so TESSA
1                                                        15                   tell me a
2                                                        14           you pretty upset.
3                      Some other text xxxxxxxxxx        20  Some other text xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: You can override the string column if you prefer. I create a new column for demo purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize number of rows you want with this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.read_csv('text.csv')
string = df.at[0,'string']
# the number of rows you want
num_of_rows = 4
endLineLimits = random.sample(range(1, string.count(' ')), num_of_rows - 1)
count = 1
for i in range(len(string)):
  if string[i] == ' ':
    if count in endLineLimits:
      string = string[:i] + ';' + string[i+1:]
    count += 1
newStrings = string.split(';')
for i in range(len(df)):
  df.at[i,'string'] = newStrings[i]
print(df)
```

Example result:

```
                   string  some_col
0  But were so TESSA tell        10
1  me a little bit more t        15
2   seems like you pretty        14
3                   upset        20
```